# Why does blender lags when I try to move objects?

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I'm using blender version 3.3.1 and when I try to move objects by using the G key on the keyboard, it lags. It goes like "not responding". Also the framerate of the viewport playback is too low. I tried so many ways to solve this problem, however, I couldn't find a solution.

I used decimate modifier and as you can see in the picture I did hide the other stuff which made the viewport playback slower.

CPU: I9 12900k
GPU: Rtx 3080 Ti
RAM: 32 GB DDR5

[image]

Comment: Sometimes there are too many verts which not obvious. Try to enable the statistic to see if something is too highpoly. It is in the Overlays menu: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html

Comment: In the picture, the vertices are near one million. But when all of the objects are shown the vertices reach near 7 million. Is it normal for blender to lag with this system config?

Comment: Many thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now figured it out. The decimation modifier degraded the performance of the viewport, while it worked fine without it.

In the end, there is no need for the decimation modifier to increase viewport rendering or performance.

Comment: Modifiers need to be recalculated on the fly on each frame. Decimate modifier in particular is quite a heavy calculation, and good for performance only once applied. Otherwise it's just yet another drag in performance.